why won't luks partition mount from fstab and crypttab entries?
I installed fedora 40 on a computer that was running parrot os. During install, I deleted all partitions except a 9TB luks data partition.
Fedora installed fine, but when I add entries in /etc/fstab: UUID=56ec7d8d-1fed-4e16-831c-0b275ffd89db /mnt/home71 ext4 defaults 0 0 and /etc/crypttab: luks-56ec7d8d-1fed-4e16-831c-0b275ffd89db UUID=56ec7d8d-1fed-4e16-831c-0b275ffd89db none discard to mount the luks data partition during boot, prompting me for a password during boot to open the luks partition, a mount -a command fails with: mount: /mnt/home71: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda5, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
I have no problem manually mounting the luks data partition using: cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 home71; mount /dev/mapper/home71 /mnt/home71
and after being mounted manually a lsblk -o name,fstype,label,uuid,mountpoint command returns:
├─sda5 crypto_LUKS 56ec7d8d-1fed-4e16-831c-0b275ffd89db 
│ └─home71 ext4 06e81132-ec1f-4685-bd73-be91c2d2b7bc /mnt/home71

I dont know why I am having such issues as I've set luks data partitions to mount this way plenty of times before.
I am starting to wonder if maybe by keeping the luks data parition when installing fedora (I have been using debian distro variants for the past 15 years), while deleting all of the other system partitions and re-partitioning that somehow the system can't recognize the previously encrypted partition, even tho it can be manually mounted?
I really don't want to have to wipe and delete the partition in order to try re-partioning and re-encrypting just to test if that works because I have a lot of data already on the partition (although it is backed up), and I just don't want to have to re-rsync it all unnecessarily. So I hope someone can maybe see something obvious I am overlooking here and save me and my HDD some time and wear and tear. Thks.


Additional details
when running command $ lsblk I get a snapshot of my current disk's partition setup.
$ lsblk
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                             8:0    0   9.1T  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                                          8:2    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda3                                          8:3    0     8G  0 part  [SWAP]
├─sda4                                          8:4    0    30G  0 part  
│ └─luks-e4d6a6b0-6889-4317-b13e-4cfad6f37f4b 253:1    0    30G  0 crypt /var
├─sda5                                          8:5    0   8.9T  0 part  
└─sda6                                          8:6    0 164.6G  0 part  
  └─luks-bfb67d91-aa41-40b1-81e9-b480e563a93e 253:0    0 164.6G  0 crypt /

The information listed for /dev/sda5, the luks data partition in question, shows less details than I would expect. I would would think TYPE column should list the partition as crypt and not jusy part, almost like the system doesn't see /dev/sda5 as a luks_crypto partition, unless I manually feed it the info to luksOpen and mount it.

you put the luks uuid in fstab (56ec…), it needs the filesystem uuid (06e8…)

@frostschutz thanks for the reply. I did try using the partition's filesystem uuid instead of the luks uuid, and no difference. I would think though that the the filesystem uuid is not avialable until the partition is luksOpened first?I have tried every variation of fstab / crypttab I could think of... maybe 10 or 12 combinations, and nothing has worked so far.
